# Sort rows of curve shaped data in python

Tags: python, sorting, scipy, data-analysis

I have a dataset that consists of 5 rows that are formed like a curve. I want to separate the inner row from the other or if possible each row and store them in a separate array. Is there any way to do this, like somehow flatten the curved data and sorting it afterwards based on the x and y values?

[image]

I would like to assign each row from left to right numbers from 0 to the max of the row. Right now the labels for each dot are not useful for me and I can't change the labels.

Here are the first 50 data points of my data set:

```
    x   y
0   -6.4165 0.3716
1   -4.0227 2.63
2   -7.206  3.0652
3   -3.2584 -0.0392
4   -0.7565 2.1039
5   -0.0498 -0.5159
6   2.363   1.5329
7   -10.7253    3.4654
8   -8.0621 5.9083
9   -4.6328 5.3028
10  -1.4237 4.8455
11  1.8047  4.2297
12  4.8147  3.6074
13  -5.3504 8.1889
14  -1.7743 7.6165
15  1.1783  6.9698
16  4.3471  6.2411
17  7.4067  5.5988
18  -2.6037 10.4623
19  0.8613  9.7628
20  3.8054  9.0202
21  7.023   8.1962
22  9.9776  7.5563
23  0.1733  12.6547
24  3.7137  11.9097
25  6.4672  10.9363
26  9.6489  10.1246
27  12.5674 9.3369
28  3.2124  14.7492
29  6.4983  13.7562
30  9.2606  12.7241
31  12.4003 11.878
32  15.3578 11.0027
33  6.3128  16.7014
34  9.7676  15.6557
35  12.2103 14.4967
36  15.3182 13.5166
37  18.2495 12.5836
38  9.3947  18.5506
39  12.496  17.2993
40  15.3987 16.2716
41  18.2212 15.1871
42  21.1241 14.0893
43  12.3548 20.2538
44  15.3682 18.9439
45  18.357  17.8862
46  21.0834 16.6258
47  23.9992 15.4145
48  15.3776 21.9402
49  18.3568 20.5803
50  21.1733 19.3041
```

Comment: Is this always a power shaped curve? Or can you have an arbitrary shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your curves have a pattern, so you could select the curve of interest using **splicing**. I had the **offset** the selection slightly to get the five curves because the first 8 points are not in the same order as the rest of the data. So the initial 8 data points are discarded. But these could be added back in afterwards if required.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x': [-6.4165, -4.0227, -7.206, -3.2584, -0.7565, -0.0498, 2.363, -10.7253, -8.0621, -4.6328, -1.4237, 1.8047, 4.8147, -5.3504, -1.7743, 1.1783, 4.3471, 7.4067, -2.6037, 0.8613, 3.8054, 7.023, 9.9776, 0.1733, 3.7137, 6.4672, 9.6489, 12.5674, 3.2124, 6.4983, 9.2606, 12.4003, 15.3578, 6.3128, 9.7676, 12.2103, 15.3182, 18.2495, 9.3947, 12.496, 15.3987, 18.2212, 21.1241, 12.3548, 15.3682, 18.357, 21.0834, 23.9992, 15.3776, 18.3568, 21.1733],
                    'y': [0.3716, 2.63, 3.0652, -0.0392, 2.1039, -0.5159, 1.5329, 3.4654, 5.9083, 5.3028, 4.8455, 4.2297, 3.6074, 8.1889, 7.6165, 6.9698, 6.2411, 5.5988, 10.4623, 9.7628, 9.0202, 8.1962, 7.5563, 12.6547, 11.9097, 10.9363, 10.1246, 9.3369, 14.7492, 13.7562, 12.7241, 11.878, 11.0027, 16.7014, 15.6557, 14.4967, 13.5166, 12.5836, 18.5506, 17.2993, 16.2716, 15.1871, 14.0893, 20.2538, 18.9439, 17.8862, 16.6258, 15.4145, 21.9402, 20.5803, 19.3041]})

# Generate the 5 dataframes
df_list = [df.iloc[i+8::5, :] for i in range(5)]

# Generate the plot
fig = plt.figure()
for frame in df_list:
    plt.scatter(frame['x'], frame['y'])
plt.show()

# Print the data of the innermost curve
print(df_list[4])
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: PLOT]

The 5th dataframe `df_list[4]` contains the data of the innermost plot.

```
          x        y
12   4.8147   3.6074
17   7.4067   5.5988
22   9.9776   7.5563
27  12.5674   9.3369
32  15.3578  11.0027
37  18.2495  12.5836
42  21.1241  14.0893
47  23.9992  15.4145
```

---

You can then add the missing data like this:

```
# Retrieve the two missing points of the inner curve
inner_curve = pd.concat([df_list[4], df[5:7]]).sort_index(ascending=True)
print(inner_curve)

# Plot the inner curve only
fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(inner_curve['x'], inner_curve['y'], color = '#9467BD')
plt.show()
```

**OUTPUT**: inner curve

```
          x        y
5   -0.0498  -0.5159
6    2.3630   1.5329
12   4.8147   3.6074
17   7.4067   5.5988
22   9.9776   7.5563
27  12.5674   9.3369
32  15.3578  11.0027
37  18.2495  12.5836
42  21.1241  14.0893
47  23.9992  15.4145
```

### Complete Inner Curve

[image: inner curve]

Comment: That's a great solution. I have to check if this sorting also works for the other data I have. I can't guarantee, that the data is always labeled in such a manner.